# Locale problem in 17.10 after upgrade

Tags: kubuntu, 17.10, locale, utf-8

I'm using Kubuntu 17.10 (fully updated). This problem may have been introduced during the upgrade to 17.04 or 17.10; I can't be sure, since I did both upgrades back to back.

Everything works as expected in the Konsole, but file names with non-ASCII characters are displayed with Unicode replacement characters (��) in KDE applications (Dolphin, Kate, etc). The display is different in other GUI applications like LibreOffice, but the file still cannot be opened. I also noticed that xterm doesn't default to UTF-8 mode anymore; this may be related.

[image: Screenshot]

I have tried both `dpkg-reconfigure locales` and `apt install --reinstall locales`, but didn't see any change after rebooting.

**/etc/default/locale**:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC="de_AT.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="de_AT.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="de_AT.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="de_AT.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="de_AT.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="de_AT.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="de_AT.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="de_AT.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="de_AT.UTF-8"
```

**locale** in Konsole (these values are set in my `.bashrc`):

```
LANG=de_AT.utf8                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
LANGUAGE=                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
LC_CTYPE=de_AT.utf8                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
LC_NUMERIC=de_AT.utf8                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
LC_TIME=en_GB.utf8                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
LC_COLLATE=POSIX                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
LC_MONETARY=de_AT.utf8
LC_MESSAGES=en_US.utf8
LC_PAPER=de_AT.utf8
LC_NAME=de_AT.utf8
LC_ADDRESS=de_AT.utf8
LC_TELEPHONE=de_AT.utf8
LC_MEASUREMENT=de_AT.utf8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=de_AT.utf8
LC_ALL=
```

**locale -a**:

```
C
C.UTF-8
POSIX
de_AT
de_AT.iso88591
de_AT.iso885915@euro
de_AT.utf8
de_AT@euro
de_BE.utf8
de_CH.utf8
de_DE.utf8
...
en_GB.utf8
...
en_US.utf8
```

([Full list](https://paste.ubuntu.com/26140645/).) I do not remember installing all those locales; I only selected `de_AT.iso88591`, `de_AT.utf8`, `de_AT@euro`, `de_DE.utf8`, `en_GB.utf8`, `en_US.utf8`.

I'm also unsure of whether to specify UTF-8 locales as `de_AT.utf8` or `de_AT.UTF-8`... both seem to be used.

What should I do now?

Comment: Use `de_AT.UTF-8` for declaring. it probably should be enough if you use the UI tools to re-set the language and data formats systemwide. Declaring language variables should not be needed in `.bashrc`.

Comment: Did you try reinstalling from scratch? That's what I would do. I have a packer template for building Ubuntu 17.10 https://gitlab.com/jcrben-play-learn/packer-desktop

Answer (score 1):

KDE overwrites your locale. change your region to a supported region.

Answer (score 0):

In KDE (Kubuntu 18.04) System settings and in Regional Settings, I added language and formats (for Region, numbers, time, currency, measurement units) and after a reboot, I was able to use Dolphin, without those non-ASCII characters in the file and folders.